# Best practice: generating queries with data sent with AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a search form in my application where data is being submitted to the backend which returns a table with the results. The query is dynamically constructed like this:

1. All fields in $_POST['data'] are filtered against an allowed list of
   fields for that certain category of query.
2. Fields that are empty are thrown away.

This is also done when saving data, by the way. Now this is totally okay with fields that consist of one word. But I have some complex JOINs in some of the queries and the PDO complains about ambiguous fields some times (for example 'id').

What should I do to best handle this situation? I don't want the user to manipulate my queries, but still want to generate them simply like I do today:

```
case 'id':
case 'company':
   $where .= ' AND `' . $field . '` = :' . $field;

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply fully qualify each field name with the name of the table which contains it. You HAVE to do this otherwise, supposing you have 2 tables "category" & "item", both with a field called "name", which contain the names of their respective objects, how else will you decide which one you want to reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are joining table A and table B, when referencing A's id column, make sure you specify A.id, that way id is no longer an "ambiguous field".